# Google Vision Mobile API with xamarin and viewrenderer shows dark preview on android phone

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-play-services

I downloaded the google mobile vision sample from:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-vision

and have no problems using their sample that demonstrates barcode, face detection, etc. the preview of the camera looks fine in terms of lighting,etc.  Their sample does not use PCL and just uses a camera screen defined in the android project.  So i created a basic ViewRender in my PCL (nothing special going on here)

```
public class CameraScanView : View
{
     public CameraScanView() { }
}
```

and changed the android activity from their sample to inherit ViewRender and moved their code from the OnCreate to the OnElementChanged such as the following:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraScanView), typeof(BarcodeScannerActivity))]
namespace VisionSample
{
public class BarcodeScannerActivity : ViewRenderer

{

    bool _isViewLoaded = false;

    QRCodeScanView _qrCodeScanView;

    CameraSource _cameraSource;

    CameraSourcePreview _preview;

    GraphicOverlay _graphicOverlay;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (!_isViewLoaded)
            {
                _isViewLoaded = true;
                _qrCodeScanView = (QRCodeScanView)e.NewElement;

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FaceTracker, null, false);

                _preview = view.FindViewById<CameraSourcePreview>(Resource.Id.preview);
                _graphicOverlay = view.FindViewById<GraphicOverlay>(Resource.Id.faceOverlay);

                var detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).SetBarcodeFormats(BarcodeFormat.QrCode).Build();

                GraphicBarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new GraphicBarcodeTrackerFactory(_graphicOverlay);
               // result.ResultReceived += Result_ResultReceived;

                detector.SetProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder(barcodeFactory).Build());

                if (!detector.IsOperational)
                {
                    // Note: The first time that an app using barcode API is installed on a device, GMS will
                    // download a native library to the device in order to do detection.  Usually this
                    // completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that download has not yet
                    // completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes.
                    //
                    // IsOperational can be used to check if the required native library is currently
                    // available.  The detector will automatically become operational once the library
                    // download completes on device.
                   // Log.Warn("SCAN", "Barcode detector dependencies are not yet available.");
                }



                _cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context, detector)
                    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                    .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                    .SetRequestedFps(30.0f)
                    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .Build();

                StartCameraSource();

                _preview.RemoveFromParent();
                SetNativeControl(_preview);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        StartCameraSource ();
    }

    protected override void OnPause ()
    {
        base.OnPause ();

        mPreview.Stop ();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        mCameraSource.Release ();

        base.OnDestroy ();
    }*/


    //==============================================================================================
    // Camera Source Preview
    //==============================================================================================

    /**
 * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists.  If the camera source doesn't exist yet
 * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
 * again when the camera source is created.
 */
    void StartCameraSource ()
    {
        try {
            _preview.Start (_cameraSource, _graphicOverlay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Android.Util.Log.Error (TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
            _cameraSource.Release ();
            _cameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    //==============================================================================================
    // Graphic Face Tracker
    //==============================================================================================

    /**
 * Factory for creating a face tracker to be associated with a new face.  The multiprocessor
 * uses this factory to create face trackers as needed -- one for each individual.
 */
    class GraphicBarcodeTrackerFactory : Java.Lang.Object, MultiProcessor.IFactory
    {            
        public GraphicBarcodeTrackerFactory (GraphicOverlay overlay) : base ()
        {
            Overlay = overlay;
        }

        public GraphicOverlay Overlay { get; private set; }

        public Android.Gms.Vision.Tracker Create (Java.Lang.Object item)
        {
            return new GraphicBarcodeTracker (Overlay);
        }
    }

    /**
 * Face tracker for each detected individual. This maintains a face graphic within the app's
 * associated face overlay.
 */
    class GraphicBarcodeTracker : Tracker
    {
        GraphicOverlay mOverlay;
        BarcodeGraphic mBarcodeGraphic;

        public GraphicBarcodeTracker (GraphicOverlay overlay) 
        {
            mOverlay = overlay;
            mBarcodeGraphic = new BarcodeGraphic (overlay);
        }

        /**
        * Start tracking the detected face instance within the face overlay.
        */
        public override void OnNewItem (int idValue, Java.Lang.Object item)
        {
            mBarcodeGraphic.Id = idValue;
        }

        /**
        * Update the position/characteristics of the face within the overlay.
        */
        public override void OnUpdate (Detector.Detections detections, Java.Lang.Object item)
        {
            mOverlay.Add (mBarcodeGraphic);
            mBarcodeGraphic.UpdateBarcode (item.JavaCast<Barcode> ());
        }

        /**
        * Hide the graphic when the corresponding face was not detected.  This can happen for
        * intermediate frames temporarily (e.g., if the face was momentarily blocked from
        * view).
        */
        public override void OnMissing (Detector.Detections detections)
        {
            mOverlay.Remove (mBarcodeGraphic);
        }

        /**
        * Called when the face is assumed to be gone for good. Remove the graphic annotation from
        * the overlay.
        */
        public override void OnDone ()
        {
            mOverlay.Remove (mBarcodeGraphic);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is now the preview screen is darker.. im using a google pixel XL (for reference)..  can anyone explain to me why simply adding a custom renderer to to the sample would result in a darker preview screen?

I have seen others say to reduce the framerate but that has no effect on this issue here.

Answer (score 1):

the issue had nothing to do with my code.

my main android style.xml had the following line:

```
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

Camera preview used a surfaceview which apparently will dim even when the rest of the screen doesn't.   my solution was to set that to false